# Watermark and Jquery Unobtrusive validation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, watermark

i added a watermark to my input using this link below
http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-watermark-effect-on-text-input/

once i added that my required validation using jquery unobtrusive stops to work.
how can i get my validation and watermark both to work?

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Person.PersonName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Person.PersonName)
    </div>

$(document).ready(function () {

var watermark = 'Person Name';

init, set watermark text and class
$('#Person_PersonName').val(watermark).addClass('watermark');

if blur and no value inside, set watermark text and class again.
$('#Person_PersonName').blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $(this).val(watermark).addClass('watermark');
    }
});

if focus and text is watermrk, set it to empty and remove the watermark class
$('#Person_PersonName').focus(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == watermark) {
        $(this).val('').removeClass('watermark');
    }
});
}
```

Comment: did you try using placeholder for watermark? try placeholder for input and see if validation works or not.

Comment: no i have not, do you have an example

Comment: <input type="text" name="key" id="searchInput" placeholder="what's up"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="key" id="searchInput" placeholder="what's up"/> worked for me
```

– kandroid Feb 18 at 15:19